# how can I assign names to Array data on MongoDB when I render it on React?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have MongoDB

```
"location" : [ 
    -34.5782531, 
    -58.4250269
],
```

Which is like this.

However, when I render this on React. I want to assign names to the array data which is like below.

```
    "location" : [ 
    "lat" : -34.5782531, 
    "lng" : -58.4250269
],
```

In order to display this coordinate on google-map-react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that's not going to change, then it could be as easy as:

```
const data = [{ lat: location[0], lng: location[1] }]
```

Just creating a new array with an object inside.

Comment: How can I create a new array with that object? I see that the function is naming each [0] and [1] but i tried on my map.js, it doesnt really do anything but giving me an error